# Query to join a table on another query

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have the following table `routes` :

```
from | to
---------
abc  | cde
cde  | abc
klm  | xyz
xyz  | klm
def  | ghi
ghi  | mno
mno  | ghi
ghi  | def
```

I then extract each unique pair of routes (in my project abc -> cde = cde -> abc) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(from,to) AS point_a, GREATEST(from,to) AS point_B FROM routes
```

And I end up with the following result :

```
point_a | point_b
-----------------
abc     | cde
klm     | xyz
def     | ghi
ghi     | mno
```

Separately I have the following table `location`

```
code | description
------------------
abc | home
cde | beach
ghi | work
xyz | club
klm | friend
...
```

I want to join this table to the result above so that I end up with the following :

```
point_a | point_b | a_description | b_description
-------------------------------------------------
abc     | cde     | home          | beach
klm     | xyz     | friend        | club
...
```

What query would do all this at once ?

I've tried to select unique pairs from `routes` then join the table `location`, or join the table `location` first then sort out the duplicates afterwards, I either get errors or the duplicates are showing up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT r.point_a, r.point_b
     , l1.description as a_description, l2.description as b_description
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(`from`,`to`) AS point_a
                    ,GREATEST(`from`,`to`) AS point_B 
                FROM routes) AS r
LEFT JOIN location l1
  ON r.point_a = l1.code
LEFT JOIN location l2
  ON r.point_b = l2.code;
```

Or `INNER JOIN` if you do not want to get null values for either point

```
SELECT r.point_a, r.point_b
     , l1.description as a_description, l2.description as b_description
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(`from`,`to`) AS point_a
                    ,GREATEST(`from`,`to`) AS point_B 
                FROM routes) AS r
INNER JOIN location l1
  ON r.point_a = l1.code
INNER JOIN location l2
  ON r.point_b = l2.code;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a47/1)

Answer (score 0):

The title is missleading, its rather an SQL question imho.
But take a look at [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) [RIGHT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) operators, you can solve this problem with all of them, depend on what you like/want.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
SELECT LEAST(r.from,r.to) AS point_a, 
       GREATEST(r.from,r.to) AS point_B,
       MAX(CASE l.code WHEN LEAST(r.from,r.to) THEN l.description END) 
          a_description,
       MAX(CASE l.code WHEN GREATEST(r.from,r.to) THEN l.description END) 
          b_description
FROM routes r
JOIN location l ON l.code IN (r.from,r.to)
GROUP BY LEAST(r.from,r.to), GREATEST(r.from,r.to)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a47/3).